# Architecture design in Android library

Tags: android, architecture

Im designing an Android library which makes it simple to display a library of media content to the user. I've designed the architecture with three layers:

- Data: Contains a model to represent and access the actual library of content.
- Business: Uses the data model to sort the content (e.g. by album, artist) and provides the sorted content to the presentation layer.
- Presentation: Displays the sorted content to the user and feeds back to the business layer when the user selects content to play.

The core idea of the library is that every media object can be displayed by showing a title, a subtitle and an artwork image. To this end, the main component of the data model is the 'DisplayableMedia' interface which is defined as:

```
public interface DisplayableMedia {
    CharSequence getTitle();
    CharSequence getSubtitle();
    Bitmap getArtwork();
}
```

This allows any type of media (songs, movies, streams etc.) to be displayed to the user, by simply defining a title, subtitle and artwork. The presentation layer then only has to be provided with a collection of DisplayableMedia objects to show, and can be agnostic to the actual media bring displayed. For example a song might be defined as:

```
public class Song implements DIsplayableMedia {
    private final File fileOnDisk;

    public Song(File fileOnDisk) {
        this.fileOnDisk = fileOnDisk;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getTitle() {
        // access the file metadata and return the song title
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getSubtitle() {
        // access the file metadata and return the song artist
    }

    public Bitmap getArtwork() {
        // access the file metadata and return the cover art
    }
}
```

Is this a bad high level design? Would it be better for the data layer to provide generic access to all sorts of metadata so that the business layer can tell the presentation layer what information to display?